# How can an object of the base class be initialised in a method of its derived class using *this?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I was trying to understand how the `this` and the `*this` keywords work in C++. From my understanding, `this` returns a pointer to the current instance of the object for which it is called, whereas `*this` returns a clone of the very same instance.

I saw a version of the below code being used in an algorithms question in a different, unrelated place. I have only kept the parts of the code that pertain to my query.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
    public:
    int a, b;
    
    void haha()
    {
        std::cout << "haha!!!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
    int c, d;
    
    void method()
    {
        Base b(*this);
        b.haha();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.method();

    return 0;
}
```

I am not able to wrap my head around how `*this` (a copy of the current `Derived` class object) is being used to instantiate an object of the Base class.

What is the OOP principle in play here?

Comment: object slicing and copy constructor. The fact that this method is inside `Derived` is irrelevant.

Comment: [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: Note that as `this` is a pointer to the current instance, `*this` isn't a copy, but the current instance itself (or a reference to it if you wish). This is not particularly relevant to this question or the answer, just something to keep in mind.

Comment: `*this` doesn't return a clone of the object, it returns a reference (which can be used to make a copy, sure). Then, you use that to call implicitly declared copy constructor `Base(const Base&)`. You can pass `Derived&` there, because `Derived` is a `Base`, but `Base` copy constructor knows nothing about `c` or `d` and copies simply `a` and `b`, as if it got a `Base&`. And that's pretty much it.

Comment: oh, you return a void.

Answer (score 1):

Both `this` and `*this` are not functions and therefore do not return anything. `*this` refers to the object pointed to by `this`. There is no copying involved by just writing

```
*this; // yes, that's a valid statement, although it has no effect
```

What would constitute a copy would be one of these:

```
Derived copy1(*this);
Derived copy2{*this};
```

However, the copying is done just as it would be if you called the constructor outside of the `Derived` member function:

```
Derived copy{d};
```

However, since `Derived` is a `Base`, writing `Base b(*this);` will call the copy constructor of `Base` with the `Base` sub-object of `*this`. That copies the `Base` portion, i.e. members `int a` and `int b`. It would be like doing this:

```
Base& dref{d}; // does not copy, slices d
Base b{dref}; // now we copy d as if it was a Base
```

Note that calling `Base::haha` would have always printed `"haha!!!"` because `Derived` inherits that function and thus calling it without creating a `Base` copy would have called the same function.